# In ReactJS, why child components re renders on dispatch in specific child component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

Child components renders in loop, but when dispatching an action addcomment or list comments action it re renders all child components instead of selected one.
See video of issue...
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/6662865?key=13c71c93a5a75039da0a386f4d6b347e

see child component code: https://jsitor.com/4Q_ulWOXl

Answer (score 0):

Although it is hard to understand from shared code. Looks like you are rendering Post Component in a loop. Can you check if the following are correct?

1. Each Post component rendered inside loop has unique `key` associated with it.
2. Check if comments added are changed in the particular post matching with payload id.
3. It can be the case in your reducer you are mapping through every post and updating with current value.

Comment: Thanks for reaching me out. The 1st and 2nd point is correct from my side but I didn't understand the 3rd point. So, I have shared you my reducer code: https://jsitor.com/E47CWRPcs